# Ios swift SHA1 encryption

Tags: android, ios, swift, swift3, sha1

In my android app i have a hashed string that i want to compare with a regular string from an edittext. I do that using the following

```
try {
         MessageDigest hashDigester = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
return (new BigInteger(1, hashDigester.digest(pin.getBytes())).toString(16)).equals(object.getPin());
```

The above code works fine. Now i am tring to do the same in ios using swift 3.0
I tried using CryptoSwift to create the hash from the edittext like this

```
text.sha1()
```

and i also tried using the below

```
extension Data {


    func hexString() -> String {
        let string = self.map{String(format:"%02x", Int($0))}.joined()
        return string
    }


    func SHA1() -> Data {
        var result = Data(count: Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH))
        _ = result.withUnsafeMutableBytes {resultPtr in
            self.withUnsafeBytes {(bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt16>) in
                CC_SHA1(bytes, CC_LONG(count), resultPtr)
            }
        }
        return result
    }

}

extension String {

    func hexString() -> String {
        return self.data(using: .utf8)!.hexString()
    }

    func SHA1() -> String {
        return self.data(using: .utf8)!.SHA1().hexString()
    }

}
```

Both gave me the same result but not the same with my android code.
Do you have any suggestions how should i adjust my swift code?

Comment: Can you an example of a string you performed sha-1 on, with the results on Android as well as on iOS (this code)?

Comment: when i insert 407 in ios it returns me 35db01d3926745bec110d5709a544e250f7fffc4 ,while in android for the same 407 returns e6de89674d9f1d7968a70dad4f41b844965b4fdc which is the correct one

Answer (score 1):

You can add some small improvements to shorten your code in Swift 4:

```
extension Data {

    var hexString: String {
        return map { String(format: "%02hhx", $0) }.joined()
    }

    var sha1: Data {
        var digest = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: Int(CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH))
        self.withUnsafeBytes({
            _ = CC_SHA1($0, CC_LONG(self.count), &digest)
        })
        return Data(bytes: digest)
    }

}

extension String {

    var hexString: String {
        return self.data(using: .utf8)!.hexString
    }

    var sha1: Data {
        return self.data(using: .utf8)!.sha1
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake! The functions where correct i was passing the wrong input